# How do I turn off the right-hand scroll bar in IE on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, scrolling, internet-explorer-10

Am working in the Classic environment in Windows 8 on Internet Explorer.  In some news pages, there are pop-up ads that appear on the right side of the screen.  When I go to close them by clicking on the X box on the upper right-hand side of the ad's window, the right-hand scroll bar suddenly pops up, preventing me from getting at anything beneath it.  How can I turn this off?

Comment: Can you provide any examples? And/or a screen shot of what you mean?  It sounds like it's site-specific.